# How can i get each string from a textBox into a string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried to do it this way in Form1:

```
private void BtnScrambleText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = false;
    BtnScrambleText.Enabled = false;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    foreach (var w in words)
    {
        if (w == " ")
        {
            sb.Append(w);
            continue;
        }

        ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(w);
        scrmbltb.GetText();
        sb.Append(scrmbltb.scrambledWord);
        textBox2.AppendText(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

The new class i have is ScrambleTextBoxText there im just getting a word from the textBox1 scramble it randomaly and then im adding the scrambled word back to the textBox2

But in textBox2 i see all the words in one long string like:

dannyhihellobyethis

There are no spaces at all between the words.
I needed it add to textBox2 with the exact spaces it was in textBox1.

If in textBox1 it was for example:

danny        hello hi yes two   four

```
moses daniel    yellow
```

So in textBox2 it should be the same line this:

danny        hello hi yes two   four

```
moses daniel    yellow
```

With same spaces with two lines down and everything.

Two problems:

1. no spaces in textBox2
2. its adding to textBox2 any word i typed in textBox1 but it should add only the words that return from my new class : scrmbltb.scrambledWord

For example if i entered in textBox1 : hi     daniel

So in textBox2 it should be :       daniel
Without the word : hi

Or if in textBox1 it was :       daniel hi    hello
So in textBox2 it will be:       daniel       hello

Comment: Honestly, have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not split them and work with this individually? For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var words = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
foreach (var w in words)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(w))
    {
        sb.Append(w);
        continue;
    }

    // do something with w
    sb.Append(w);
}
```

This algorithm would maintain all the spaces, but allow you manipulate `w` before appending it.

Comment: Michael Perrenoud im getting an error on the line if (w == ' ') Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'

Comment: @HaimKashi, change that to `w == " "`.

Comment: Edited my question since its not working good yet with the spaces and the words its adding to textBox2. please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and simple:

```
string text = textBox1.Text;

string[] words = text.Split(new string[] { }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string word in words)
{
    textBox2.Text += " " + ChangeWord(word);
}
```

and if you don't like the leading space:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Trim();
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you want to change the words ad-hoc as well. In that case, see above change and add this:

```
private string ChangeWord(string word)
{
    // Do something to the word
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = textbox1.Text.split(' ');
string[] ignoreChars = new string[] { ",", "." };

foreach(string t in str)
{
   if(!ignoreChars.Contains(t)) //by this way, we are skipping the stuff you want to do to the words
   {
     if(!int.TryParse(t)) // same here
     {
         //dosomething to t
         // t = t + "asd";
     }
   }
   textBox2.Text += " " + t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do as follows:

```
String str=TextBox1.Text;
String[] tokens = str.split(" ");

for(int i=0;i<tokens.length();i++)
{
  String retVal = tokens[i];
}

TextBox2.Text=retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getline or readline for C# which will get the entire line in the text box and then store it in a temp variable.